# [JS][React] Creating Custom Avatar Group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I am trying to create a custom avatar. However, nothing is being rendered since by the time that the avatar component is being re-rendered, the count for the avatar is already greater causing it to hide or return null once it is re-rendered.

Scenario: The filter should be done only inside the avatar as I am trying to fetch a data via hook in real situation so doing the filtering in the avatar group component is an unnecessary solution.

Here is my avatar group component:

```
function AvatarGroup() {
    const avatars = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
    const [renderedAvatar, setRenderedAvatar] = useState(0);

    return (
        <Stack direction='row'>
            {
                avatars.map((avatar) => {
                    console.log();

                    return (
                        <AvatarRenderer
                            key={avatar}
                            avatar={avatar}
                            renderedAvatar={renderedAvatar}
                            setRenderedAvatar={setRenderedAvatar}
                        />
                    );
                })
            }
        </Stack>
    );
}
```

Here is my avatar component:

```
const AvatarRenderer = memo(({ avatar, renderedAvatar, setRenderedAvatar }) => {
    const doNotRender = ['A', 'C', 'E'];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!doNotRender.includes(avatar) || renderedAvatar < 5) {
            setRenderedAvatar((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
        }
    }, [avatar]);

    if (doNotRender.includes(avatar) || renderedAvatar > 4) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Box
            width='24px'
            height='24px'
            backgroundColor='#f3f3f3'
            padding='8px'
            margin='4px'
        >
            { avatar }
        </Box>
    );
});
```

What I expect here is for it to render:

B, D, F, G, H

And then after fixing this issue, would add a +2 which means there are 2 avatars -  I and J.

Main issue is the re-render of the child component Avatar which returns null resulting to no avatar being shown. Any idea of a better approach is appreciated.